# Pass a method name as string to other method of different class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, function-pointers

I have val1.rb and val2.rb, which have methods called `foo1` and `foo2` respectively, one start-up script called startup.rb and one main script called core.rb.

The startup script creates objects `main_obj` of the class from core.rb and objects `obj1` and `obj2` of classes of `val1` and `val2` respectively.

Core wishes to call a method which it accepts as an argument.

Below is the code that I wrote but it throws an error saying undefined method 'foo1'.

```
# #### foo1.rb #### #
class Test1
 def foo1(par1)
  puts "par1 is :#{par1}"
 end
end

# #### core.rb #### #
class Core
 def main_test (validation_obj, validation_method)
   par1 = 'sample'
   validation_obj.send :validation_method, par1
   # other way #
   # validation_method.call(par1)
 end 
end

# #### startup.rb #### #
require_relative 'core'
require_relative 'foo1'
require_realtive 'foo2'

main_obj = Core.new
testobj_1 = Test1.new
testobj_2 = Test2.new

method_name = 'foo1' # ==> want to pass this method as string 
main_obj.main_test(testobj_1, method_name)
method_name = 'foo2'
main_obj.main_test(testobj_2, method_name)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with there being several files to deal with. You could simplify by just defining the classes you will be using. You need to also be more clear about the question you are asking. You say, "core wishes to call a method..".  What is `core`? You've spoken of a file "core.rb" and a class `Core`. Give the method you are speaking of a name, class and argument and say what you expect the method to return. A specific example would be helpful. Also, `main_test.new` implies that `main_test` is a class, which it is not.

Comment: just change `:validation_method` to `validation_method` you are creating a `symbol` when you write `:validation_method` and it is trying to call a method called `validation_method`. Instead of creating this symbol just simply pass the argument on. `validation_obj.send validation_method, par1`

Comment: @engineersmnky, Thanks for for your inputs.  Initially, I had tried passing just 'validation_method'. However, it threw me same error of undefined method which made me to change the string to symbol (I believe using ':' was my wrong approach to covert to symbol).

Comment: You're getting there! Implement @engineersmnky's suggestion and `Test1#foo1` will execute. Executing `Test2#foo2` will be more difficult considering that you have no class `Test2`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland and all, I sincerely apologize for the vagueness of my question. I edited the part of code that was wrong.

Comment: Assuming that we have class Test2 as well, the suggestion provided to pass the method name directly without converting to symbol does not work for Test1#foo1 at least in this scenario. However, if I convert the method name to symbol, it works great.

Comment: Rahulkumar, you have nothing to apologize for. You are learning and obviously trying hard. The main thing is that you listen and make corrections, as you have done. You are correct about the need to convert to a symbol (but you know that now).

Comment: @CarySwoveland you should not need to convert to a `symbol`. Take this `a = 12; a.send("+",12) #=> 24; a.send(:+,12) == a.send("+",12) #=> true` Or even to use his example `Test1.new.send("foo1",12) #=> par is :12`

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks! I won't forget that (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to transform your string in a symbol

```
"foo".to_sym
```

And your code:

```
class Core
 def main_test (validation_obj, validation_method)
   par1 = 'sample'
   validation_obj.send validation_method.to_sym, par1
   # other way #
   # validation_method.call(par1)
 end 
end
```

I believe this will make work your code.

Comment: `#send` works with a `String` problem is that he is creating a symbol not referencing a variable. When he wrote `:validation_method` it does not reference the `validation_method` argument but instead just passes that symbol.

Comment: True. I saw that. The question is also so confuse. Hard to understand what he really want.

Comment: Andre, I agree, but when the question is as vague as it is here, I suggest you seek clarification in a comment before answering.

Comment: Andre, Cary , engineersmnky, appreciate your inputs. I accepted the answer which solves the problem in my case.